# What is the Postgresql opposite of the unnest function to create an array from a resultset

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a dept --< emp schema. I want create a resultset which joins dept and emp with a row for each dept and a column which is an array of emps in each dept.

So something like `select dept_name, xxxxxxx from dept,emp where emp_dept_id = dept_id`

returning

```
department1 | fred,bill,joe
department2 | faith, hope, charity
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend arrays:

```
select d.dept_name, array_agg(e.name)
from dept d join 
     emp e
     on e.emp_dept_id = d.dept_id
group by d.dept_name;
```

You can also use `string_agg(e.name, ',')` if you really prefer a string.

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- Qualify all column names in a query that references multiple tables.
- Use table aliases so the query is easier to write and read.

Comment: perfect. "array_agg()" was the secret sauce I was looking for.

Comment: I ended up using the "string_agg()" version as the resultset needs to be passed through a database library which may or may not handle arrays correctly, and I would need to figure out how it mapped them to JSON. Since my array elements are all numeric, it's safer to concatenate them with comma delimiters and let all of the middleware treat it as a string. Thanks again.